# How best to get past JS linting non-issue

Tags: jshint

I have a file 'AppConfig.js' that defines an object in a namespace like so:

```
MyNamespace.MyObject
```

In another file, I an using the /// style to reference that object, and later in the code I'm creating an instance of the object:

```
var appConfig = new MyNamespace.MyObject();
appConfig.version = "1.0"
something.constant('config',appConfig);
```

The problem is that JSHint reports "MyNamespace" is a bad option because it says "doesn't understand 'MyNamespace'. That makes sense. According to the JSHint docs, I see I can put a trailing comment to ignore the entire ling, but then I get errors that 'appConfig' is not defined. The next option is to wrap all three of those lines in a JSHint start/end ignore block.

The two issues with this is that I'll lose all JSHinting over code that uses that external object definition (which will occur a LOT throughout my app) but in addition I expect my codebase will be littered with these comments. If I just omit the JSHint ignore stuff, I'll get the hits showing up in my JSHint report. With a large app, this is going to get REAL noisy real fast... almost making the JSHint report ineffective...

Is there a better way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--prereq` flag in the CLI version:

```
jshint anotherfile.js --prereq AppConfig.js
```

Use the `global` pragma via an inline comment in the browser version:

```
/* global MyNamespace */
```

**References**

- [JsHint CLI Flags: prereq](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/wiki/CLI-flags#--prereq)
- [JsHint Documentation: globals](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/wiki/Documentation#globals)